# Simplehtmldom get first element

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When I parse some html and get an array of html elements I want to get the first item. Here is the code:

```
    $url  = getLink($good);
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    $offers = array_filter($html->find('div.b-offers'), function($node) {
        return $node->class == 'b-offers'; // If this only class is set
    });

    // $offer    = $offers[0];  // <---- look here
    foreach ($offers as $offer) {
        $price    = $offer->find('span.b-prices__num', 0)->innertext();
        break;
    }
```

It works only if I use foreach and the break immediately. But why $offer = $offers[0] doesnt work? If I write this way there will be an error here:

```
$price = $offer->find('span.b-prices__num', 0)->innertext();
```

Like call find() function on a non-object.

Also another question is: is it possible to rewrite the code where I use array_filter function to get an element which has only one class "b-offers"? I remember I tried some different approaches like

```
$html->find('div[class="b-offers"]')
```

or kind of, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$offer    = $offers[0];` doesn't work because `array_filter` doesn't return a 0-index based array. it preserves the key of the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

**why $offer = $offers[0] doesnt work?**
I think because at this point `$offers` is still an object and not an array

**to get an element which has only one class "b-offers"**
try `$html->find('div.b-offers');`

Comment: Hm, but I was able to get the first element when I followed DebZer0 answer, I just write $offer = reset($offers). Well, I tried to do what you said (find div.b-offers) but I think I got such elements like "b-offers another-class" also..